# How to get Product ID of an app installed on Win8 using power shell

Tags: powershell, windows-store-apps

I tried following code:

```
 $installedapps = Get-AppxPackage

 $aumidList = @()
 foreach ($app in $installedapps)
 {
      foreach ($id in (Get-AppxPackageManifest).package.applications.application.id)
   {
    #id
   }
 }
$aumidList
```

But this is application ID. How to get Product ID ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following PowerShell code sample to create a function that returns a [PSCustomObject] of Microsoft application information with the Product ID of store apps for the specified and installed application package name. The function queries the Microsoft Store web site for the respective app package per signature.

```
# List all packages to get installed package names
# Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers
$packageName = 'Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge'

function FindAppXInfo( 
  $packageName, 
  $region = 'en-us', 
  $searchClass = 'c-hyperlink' ) {
  $package = Get-AppxPackage -Name $packageName
  $pFamilyName = $package.PackageFamilyName
  $pManifest = $package | Get-AppxPackageManifest
  $pAppId = $pManifest.Package.Applications.Application[0].Id
  $aumid = '{0}!{1}' -f $pFamilyName, $pAppId
  $pAppInfo = [Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInfo]::GetFromAppUserModelId($aumid)
  if ($package.SignatureKind -eq [Windows.ApplicationModel.PackageSignatureKind]::Store) {
    $query = 'https://www.microsoft.com/{0}/search/explore?q={1}+{2}' -f $region, $packageName, $package.PublisherId
    $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $query
    $links = $request.Links | Where Class -eq $searchClass
    $firstLink = $links[0]
    $ProductId = $firstLink.href.SubString($firstLink.href.LastIndexOf('/')+1)
    $storeLink = 'ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId={0}' -f $ProductId
  }
  $obj = [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
    PackageFamilyName = $pFamilyName
    FullName = $pAppInfo.Package.Id.FullName
    ApplicationId = $pAppId
    AppUserModelId = $aumid
    ProductID = $ProductId
    DirectLink = $firstLink.href
    MsftStoreLink = $storeLink
    DisplayName = $pAppInfo.Package.DisplayName
    LogoFilePath = $pAppInfo.Package.Logo.OriginalString
    PublisherDisplayName = $pAppInfo.Package.PublisherDisplayName
    InstalledDate = $pAppInfo.Package.InstalledDate
    InstalledPath = $pAppInfo.Package.InstalledPath
    Description = $pAppInfo.DisplayInfo.Description
    PackageVersion = $package.Version
    PublisherId = $package.PublisherId
    Publisher = $package.Publisher
  }
  return $obj
}

FindAppXInfo($packageName)
```